# A file in a git repo isn't showing up on the remote server

Tags: git

I had a file named threex.windowresize.js, but I deleted it. Now I've added a file called THREEx.WindowResize.js to the repository in the same location, and I've noticed that the file doesn't show up on the remote server... what should I do?

Comment: what operating systems are running on your local machine and the remote server? it sounds like you may be running into an issue with how each filesystem handles case sensitivity. also, can you be more specific with regards what commands you ran to remove it the file from being tracked in the repository? did you do a `git pull` on the remote server?

Comment: no `git pull` just a `git rm THREEx.WindowResize.js`, and yes, I'm using windows. Didn't think of that. I "fixed" the issue by renaming the file, but more graceful approaches are always welcome.